# VBA error loading .NET COM Visible library

Tags: .net, vba, com

I am trying to register and use a .NET library that I have created in C#.NET and up until now I have been getting Visual Studios to "Register COM" on build.

I am now trying to go through the process of a how I might deploy so I have the following which registers the DLL:

`"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\"regasm.exe "%~dp0myDLL.dll"`

This is Windows XP and the folder with the batch script above and the myDLL.dll sits on the desktop.

which registers the DLL file, but when I come to add a reference to it in VBA I am getting the following:

`Error in loading DLL`

I can see the library in the References list and the location looks correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found here: ["Register for COM Interop" vs "Make assembly COM visible"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699767/register-for-com-interop-vs-make-assembly-com-visible)

I needed: `regasm.exe /codebase /tlb path-to-dll.dll`