# Exposing .NET events to COM?

Tags: c#, vba, events, com

I've been trying to expose and fire an event to a VBA client. So far on the VBA client side, the event is exposed and I see the method event handling method added to my module class however the VBA event handling method does not fire. For some reason, when debugging the event is null. Modifying my code with synchronously did not help either.

For the record, I've checked other SO questions but they didn't help.

Any good answers will be appreciated.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("56C41646-10CB-4188-979D-23F70E0FFDF5")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IWebEvents))]
[ProgId("MyAssembly.MyClass")]
public class MyClass : ServicedComponent, IMyClass
{
    public string _address { get; private set; }
    public string _filename { get; private set; }

    [DispId(4)]
    public void DownloadFileAsync(string address, string filename)
    {
        _address = address;
        _filename = filename;
        System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => wc.DownloadFile(_address, _filename))
            .ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            if (null != this.OnDownloadCompleted)
                OnDownloadCompleted();
        });
    }
    public event OnDownloadCompletedEventHandler OnDownloadCompleted;
}

[ComVisible(false)]
public delegate void OnDownloadCompletedEventHandler();

[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IWebEvents
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void OnDownloadCompleted();
}
```

Comment: Try declaring MyClass parent = this before Task.  In your task use parent.OnDownloadCompleted.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The key concept in .NET code is to define event(s) as method(s) on a separate interface and connect it to the class via `[ComSourceInterfacesAttribute]`. In the example this is done with this code `[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IEvents))]` where `IEvents` interface defines the event(s)  which should be handled on COM client.

*Note to event naming:

Event names defined in c# class and interface method names defined on interface must be the same. In this example `IEvents::OnDownloadCompleted` corresponds with `DemoEvents::OnDownloadCompleted`*.

Then a second interface is defined which represents the public API of the class itself, here it is called `IDemoEvents`. On this interface methods are defined which are called on COM client.

> C# code (builds to COMVisibleEvents.dll)

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.EnterpriseServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace COMVisibleEvents
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("8403C952-E751-4DE1-BD91-F35DEE19206E")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface IEvents
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        void OnDownloadCompleted();

        [DispId(2)]
        void OnDownloadFailed(string message);
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("2BF7DA6B-DDB3-42A5-BD65-92EE93ABB473")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface IDemoEvents
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        Task DownloadFileAsync(string address, string filename);
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("56C41646-10CB-4188-979D-23F70E0FFDF5")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IEvents))]
    [ProgId("COMVisibleEvents.DemoEvents")]
    public class DemoEvents : ServicedComponent, IDemoEvents
    {
        public delegate void OnDownloadCompletedDelegate();
        public delegate void OnDownloadFailedDelegate(string message);

        public event OnDownloadCompletedDelegate OnDownloadCompleted;
        public event OnDownloadFailedDelegate OnDownloadFailed;

        private string FileNamePath(string filename) 
            => Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), filename);

        public async Task DownloadFileAsync(string address, string filename)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    await webClient
                        .DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(address), FileNamePath(filename))
                        .ContinueWith(t =>
                        {
                            if (t.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
                            {
                                var failed = OnDownloadFailed;
                                failed?.Invoke(GetExceptions(t));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var completed = OnDownloadCompleted;
                                completed?.Invoke();
                            }
                        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

            #region Local

            string GetExceptions(Task task)
            {
                var innerExceptions = task.Exception?.Flatten().InnerExceptions;
                if (innerExceptions == null)
                    return string.Empty;
                var builder = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var e in innerExceptions)
                    builder.AppendLine(e.Message);
                return builder.ToString();
            }

            #endregion Local
        }
    }
}
```

> regasm

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>regasm C:\Temp\COMVisibleEvents\bin\Debug\COMVisibleEvents.dll /tlb: C:\Temp\COMVisibleEvents\bin\Debug\COMVisibleEvents.tlb
```

> Register for COM interop

Use this setting during development process on your local computer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3700057/863240

> VBA client reference to `*.tlb` file

Add reference to `*tlb` which was generated by `regasm`. Here the name of this `tlb` file is `COMVisibleEvents`.

[image]

Here Excel User Form was used as VBA client. After the button was clicked, the method `DownloadFileAsync` was executed and when this method completes the event was caught in handler `m_eventSource_OnDownloadCompleted`. In this example you can download the Airport Codes from datahub.io.

> VBA client code (MS Excel 2016)

```vb
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents m_eventSource As DemoEvents

Private Sub DownloadFileAsyncButton_Click()
    m_eventSource.DownloadFileAsync "https://datahub.io/core/airport-codes/r/airport-codes.json", "airport-codes.json"
End Sub

Private Sub m_eventSource_OnDownloadCompleted()
    MsgBox "Download completed..."
End Sub

Private Sub m_eventSource_OnDownloadFailed(ByVal message As String)
    MsgBox "Download failed. " & message, vbCritical, "Error"
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set m_eventSource = New COMVisibleEvents.DemoEvents
End Sub
```

> Result

[image]

> Source code is on GitHub too:

https://github.com/ddmail/COMVisibleEvents.git

Comment: Why does the `DemoEvents` `OnDownloadCompleted` event is private here ?

Comment: I wonder if the event is *accessible* from VBA if declared this way. The declaration of COM events always bugged me anyway.

Comment: I suppose that in vba this doesnt metter, there you have the event accessible via the interface.