# Return a response value from a c# Library to VBA

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I have an application and want to use `Twilio-SendGrid` to send out some emails. I have looked a their c# suggestion, and created a basic `DLL/COM` file which works fine, but in addition to their example, I also want to return the `"StatusCode"` back to the `Access` application.

I need to establish, if the proposed static variable approach that I am using is a good way to go, or if I should use a different method.

```
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using SendGrid;
    using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;

    namespace TSLib_SendGrid
    {
        public class SendGrid
        {
            public static string strResponse = "";

            public string SendNow(string apiKey)
            {
                Execute(apiKey).Wait();
                return strResponse;
            }   

            static async Task<string> Execute(string apiKey)
            {
                var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
                var from = new EmailAddress("abc@123.com", "From user");
                var to = new EmailAddress("xyz@987.com", "To recipient");
                var subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
                var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
                var htmlContent = "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with C#</strong>";
                var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
                var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

                strResponse = response.StatusCode.ToString();
                return strResponse;
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Neither COM nor VBA know about Task or async await. If possible, the VBA macro should access the `Result` property of the returned task, or call the `Wait()` method, to block until the task finishes. It's probably better to turn `Execute` itself into a synchronous method, by using `.Result` to retrieve `SendEmailAsync`'s result

Comment: Another option would be to raise events from your `SendGrid` class, as shown [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39511528/exposing-net-events-to-com).

Comment: Thanks for that - but I have noticed that when the VBA function is called, which in-turn calls the COM object,  it doesn't give me the response until everything has finished correctly.  As for the other link, I'll take a look.

Comment: What's the question then? What does the VBA code look like? Did you try to read the `Result` property?

Comment: The question was about how I use the variable, and if I am doing things correctly (I'm still learning .Net).  The .Net application creates the DLL/COM file, Access/VBA References it and initiates the email.  Ultimately, I just want to get the StatusCode back into the VBA function.  What I have works, but is it an ok way to do it?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. If  it works, then what are the things you worry about?

Comment: My apologies if it's unclear - I'm just trying to make sure that what I am doing (in .Net), is technically a good way to do it.  Hence the question, "I need to establish, if the proposed static variable approach that I am using is a good way to go, or if I should use a different method."

Comment: That should be fine. thus your VBA will be:            - strResult = Myobj.SendNow("apiKey")